# jQuery monitor table for change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a plugin that shows/hides columns in a table.

However I also use several other plugins on the table, hence the table is quite dynamic.

I am looking for a way to monitor the table for whenever something happens to it.

eg,

rows are added, rows are removed, rows are hidden...

is there a general `.change()` event for any dom element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) to detect when rows have been added/removed:

```
$("tr").livequery(function() {
  console.log($(this) + " was added");
}, function() {
  console.log($(this) + " was removed");
});
```

Comment: Just some information: http://jupiterjs.com/news/why-you-should-never-use-jquery-live

Comment: @Jared I know the guys at Jupiter know what they're talking about, but I thought this post was a bit inflammatory. From the title, I was expecting them to say it had a gaping security hole, but as it turns out, it's just that it's slower and not so reusable as `.delegate()` which can't always be used to do what `.live()` and `.livequery()` can do.

Comment: @blowski - True, which is why I said "just some information". As in "to consider". ;)

Comment: @Jared Sorry, wasn't intended as a criticism of you - just a response to the post itself. It was a valid comment with a useful and relevant link.

Answer (score 4):

You could bind to DOM events:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event){
        console.log('inserted '+event.target.nodeName + ', parent: '+event.relatedNode.getAttribute('id'));
    });
    $(document).bind('DOMNodeRemoved', function(event){
        console.log('removed');
    });
    $(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(event){
        console.log('modified '+event.target.getAttribute('id'));
    });

    $('#tbl').append($('<tr></tr>').
                    attr('id', 'newrow'));
});
```

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dbrecht/taEXU/)**

Of course, your elements would have to be given identifiers to make this useful at all.

Comment: Aren't these events specific to Firefox?

Comment: @eli: nope - those ones are common w3c events (just tried the fiddle in Chrome). There are others that *are* defined as being Mozilla specific, but these aren't in that list.

Comment: But then, we all know that IE doesn't follow w3c events, so this code won't work there.

Comment: @eli: unfortunately, true enough (just tried it).. gah. when will MS just give up and *buy* a browser rather than continually being years behind others? :P

Comment: @Demian Brecht - Even in IE9?

Comment: @jared: not sure, haven't tried (and i don't have windows at home, so can't test it) - perhaps you could let me know? :)

Comment: @DemianBrecht: Your Fiddle seems to be gone: "We're truly sorry, but there is no such page." :/

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is not a cross-browser change event for the manipulation of the DOM. You have a couple options:

1. Use the functions that manipulate the table to also do your other actions.
2. Create a pub/sub system to publish and subscribe to your own custom table events.